# Troubleshooting debian 6 server restarts

Tags: debian, mono, server-crashes

A day ago I have installed Mono 2.10 ( for C# 4 support ). Since then server was randomly restarting whenever there is C# app running with no error messages or anything.

**uname -a**

```
Linux ns3001599.ovh.net 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59
UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**mono -V**

```
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-4)
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc, Xamarin, Inc and Contributors.
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Some lines in log files are overlapping I guess because it did not finish writing that line before server restarted.

```
Jul 23 07:09:01 ns3001599 postfix/qmgr[3154]: C91AD60122CJul 23 07:10:10 ns3001599 kernel: imklog 4.6.4, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jul 23 07:10:10 ns3001599 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.4" x-pid="2407" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Jul 23 07:10:10 ns3001599 kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jul 23 07:10:10 ns3001599 kernel: Linux version 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 (root@kernel-64.ovh.net) (gcc version 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) ) #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59 UTC 2012
Jul 23 07:10:10 ns3001599 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/bzImage-3.2.13-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/md1 ro quiet
```

If you will need more information, tell me.
Thank you.

**Updates**

- Installed kernel 2.6.32 from Debian repository. Problem still was not fixed.
- Memtest did not report anything bad, tests passed.
- Updated to official testing Debian kernel 3.2 seemed to fix problem. ( so far almost 24 hours up time, allot better than was before at least )

Comment: Based on the kernel version and your update, am I correct to assume you are running a custom version of Debian on OVH's private cloud platfrom (virtual machines)? Have you tried contacting them about your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that software such as mono can randomly crash the Linux kernel. I think it's merely coincedence that the crashes started happening after installing mono.

You need to look at other causes, such as memory errors or disk errors. Or possibly a kernel bug. The kernel you appear to be using doesn't look like it's from a Debian repository, is it custom built? Try a kernel from Debian stable, see if that helps. Also try to do a memory test to see if you have any errors, check your disk for bad blocks.

Some tools to use:

- http://www.memtest.org/
- badblocks /dev/sdXX

Overheating, another cause of random crashes and restarts.

Comment: Its Ovh's version of Debian. I have downgraded to standard Debian kernel 2.6. Same stuff is happening. Entire server is completely idle at the moment. I will try memtest in a moment.

Comment: A thorough memtest can take half a day or more depending on memory size (speaking from experience testing 32+ GB).